# Error with a custom folder

Tags: windows, registry, guid, explorer, clsid

I've been working on this for days but still cannot figure out how to do this: creating a custom folder.

Here's some information that I used:

- [Source 1](http://www.liutilities.com/products/registrybooster/tweaklibrary/tweaks/10082/#RegistryEntries)
- [Source 2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn889934(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Source 3](http://www.pctools.com/guides/registry/detail/73/)

The major difference between the goal of these links and me is the fact that I am not trying to pin my folder to somewhere else. The only thing that I want to do is to create a redirect to a folder's subdirectory.

Here's my simple diagram:
[image: Diagram of the Main Directory]

So if I open **Main Directory**(the yellow part), desktop.ini and the system attribute of **Main Directory** will call up my custom CLSID ([Explanation](https://superuser.com/questions/142420/folder-vs-file-folder-can-i-create-a-folder-from-the-command-line)) and redirect my access to **Redirect Folder** automatically. My custom CLSID will also add an option in the context menu(the list that appears when right-clicked) to execute a .cmd file. The .cmd file will enable the user to access **Hidden Folder** when the correct password is typed.

So here're my registry keys:

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{a79ff1d1-166e-4f20-967f-5aa2a0c19cd0}] @=""
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{a79ff1d1-166e-4f20-967f-5aa2a0c19cd0}\DefaultIcon]
>   @=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
>   00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,00,68,00,\
>   65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,2d,00,34,00,00,\
>   00
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{a79ff1d1-166e-4f20-967f-5aa2a0c19cd0}\InProcServer32]
>   @="shell32.dll" "ThreadingModel"="ApartMent"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{a79ff1d1-166e-4f20-967f-5aa2a0c19cd0}\Instance]
>   "CLSID"="{0E5AAE11-A475-4c5b-AB00-C66DE400274E}"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{a79ff1d1-166e-4f20-967f-5aa2a0c19cd0}\Instance\InitPropertyBag]
>   "TargetFolderPath"="C:\Custom\Location\to\the\Main\Directory"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{a79ff1d1-166e-4f20-967f-5aa2a0c19cd0}\Shell]
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{a79ff1d1-166e-4f20-967f-5aa2a0c19cd0}\Shell\Open
>   Vault]
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{a79ff1d1-166e-4f20-967f-5aa2a0c19cd0}\Shell\Open
>   Vault\Command] @="cmd /c Open.cmd"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{a79ff1d1-166e-4f20-967f-5aa2a0c19cd0}\ShellFolder]
>   "Attributes"=dword:00000000

It looked like this would work just as intended, but it had a flaw: my **Main Directory** did not actually redirect me to **Redirect Folder**. Here's my evidence:

- When I right-clicked, every creating option was gone (Create new folder, text file, etc.)
- When I create a file using a 3rd party software that was in the context menu, it did not create the file in **Redirect folder** but instead in **Main Directory**
- Most importantly, when I Shift + right clicked and opened a command prompt, it showed my current directory as **Main Directory** instead of **Redirect Folder**

So what I'm trying to ask is this: how do I completely redirect my **Main Directory** access to **Redirect Folder** and keep my **Hidden Folder** opening option in the context menu?

Comment: I don't see any [tag:batch-file] code.  So I am not sure what you want help with.

Comment: @Squashman I was also going to ask about the script that I'll use for opening the hidden folder, but I figured it would be better to ask separately. Sorry for the inconvenience. I'll remove the tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know how this works, but I found a way around.

> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{a79ff1d1-166e-4f20-967f-5aa2a0c19cd0}\shellex]
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{a79ff1d1-166e-4f20-967f-5aa2a0c19cd0}\shellex{000214EE-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
>   @="{0AFACED1-E828-11D1-9187-B532F1E9575D}"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{a79ff1d1-166e-4f20-967f-5aa2a0c19cd0}\shellex{000214F9-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
>   @="{0AFACED1-E828-11D1-9187-B532F1E9575D}"

The first step is to add above lines to the Registry.

After adding these, I created a shortcut file(.lnk) of a random folder(excluding self and some other special folders).

When I moved the .lnk file to the **Main folder**, I could access to **create new** option from my context menu.